# A way to prepare a manual for update

Tags: links, update

I am writing a manual for my students and I use as resource many blogs posted by the community. I am aware of how fast links to websites can turn obsolete. Every semester I want to make sure the links in my document are up-to-date and working. Is there a way in latex to check if the links are at least not returning an error (like 404). Or do I have to write an independent script to verify this?
Thanks!

Comment: While checking if Acrobat can do it (no) they recommended the AutoBookmark plugin.  You could also create an index of links and simply run through them all.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. The gathering of all links in the index is a great idea. However I did not understand what you mean with "simply run through them all". Like clicking in each of them?

Comment: Alas, yes.  "Life is hard, then you die."

Comment: I think I will go with parsing the .ind file, curl the sites :-) and print a report. I am too lazy to click ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In LuaLaTeX, you can check the links directly, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{luacode}
http = require("socket.http")

function check(url)
    local _, c = http.request(url)
    if c ~= 200 then
        tex.sprint(" (INVALID)") -- print to document
        texio.write("Warning: " .. url .. " invalid") -- print to TeX log
    end
end

\end{luacode}
\newcommand{\checkedlink}[1]{\url{#1}\directlua{check("#1")}}

\begin{document}

\checkedlink{https://google.com/}

\checkedlink{https://iujwhfelfwiejowi.com/}

\end{document}
```

The command `\checkedlink` prints the link using the `\url` macro and
calls the Lua function `check()`. This function tries to access the given URL using a HTTP request. If the return code is not 200, it appends *(INVALID)* to the link in the document and writes a warning to the log.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I tried your script and it is giving me an error: luacode needs to run in lualatex. (line 51: Package luacode Error: LuaTeX is required for this package. Aborting.. to prevent additional errors.}... and the cascade or errors follow)
I am using TexStudio and I have lualatex in my system and in my TexStudio settings (lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex). I ran your code in the command line using Lualatex and it works perfectly. I will look for TexStudio options to read the tex file using Lualatex and not any other I have in the system. Thanks again.

Comment: Please feel free to accept this answer if it helps you.